# How to create different pdf invoices using TCPDF inside loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am trying to generate multiple/different PDF files using TCPDF in Codeigniter.
I have written a function which will create invoices details in DB for next 14 days, what I want is to create PDF files with these invoices. **TCPDF** is working only for 1 invoice, when I calls the invoice_generation function inside loop, it's giving error

> TCPDF ERROR: Empty font family

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311/thread/d1763b6e/ and see if that answers your questions

Comment: I have already taken a look at  that, I am able to figure out the issue. It's resolved now. inside loop, $this->pdf was not initializing every time resulting in overwriting the first pdf  everytime.